# Generate public ssh key from private key

Tags: linux, ssh

I have private ssh (id_rsa) key.

How I can generate public key from it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The option `-y` outputs the public key. From the linux manual for the `ssh-keygen` command:

> `-y` ---- This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print
>   an
>                OpenSSH public key to stdout.

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

As a side note, the comment of the public key is lost. I've had a site which required the comment (Launchpad?), so you need to edit ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and append a comment to the first line with a space between the comment and key data. An example public key is shown truncated below.

```
ssh-rsa AAAA..../VqDjtS5 ubuntu@ubuntu
```

If you want a scripted way to add a comment and also add the pubkey to your `authorized_keys` file, you can do...

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa    | \
    sed 's/$/ comment-goes-here/' | \
    tee ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub         | \
    tee -a authorized_keys
```