# How to identify github user with ssh key?

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I want to disable a working git ssh key. But do not know the owner of the ssh key.
For both disabling the key or removing the user, I would need to know the user details.

The file:`.git/config` does not include the user information.

And I face the below error when I try to commit

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run 

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

FYI: The key is SAML authorized.

Can I know if there is a way we can find the git user using the ssh key?

Comment: You can inspect `authorized_keys` and afterwards take a look into the public key usually in the comment part you should see the user or machine `<algorithm> <key> <comment>`

Comment: Unfortunately, the machine only has a private key, no public key found inside the machine.

Comment: You can use any user to commit, the SSH key is for pushing.

Comment: You can convert a private key to public: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38290956/7976758

Comment: @phd But the generated public key will not have the user email in the comment right?

Comment: @DwarakanathThoppe Alas, no.

Comment: @dan1st Yes I assumed that, I had tried it in vain to see what the user email will be if git user is not configured. Thought it will use the user email from ssh user if no user configured.

Comment: Convert the private key to the public key, then use that to authenticate at GitHub to find out who GItHub believe that key-pair belongs to (`ssh -Tv git@github.com` using that key-pair). Note that Git itself is not involved in this process—it's purely GitHub and ssh.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to Github using that public key

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Returns:

```
Hi githubUser! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```